# Error with notification names while converting code to Swift 4.2

Tags: nsnotifications, xcode10, swift4.2

The code below was working fine before Swift 4.2:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
```

When I click the 'Fix' option, it becomes:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
```

But it is still marked an error. Here is the explanation:

```
Type 'NSNotification.Name' has no member 'UIResponder'
```

And then I tried to delete 'UIResponder':

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.
```

...but I don't know how should I complete it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The correct form is:

```
UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification
```

...so, your code becomes:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    self, 
    selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(notification:)), 
    name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, 
    object: nil
)
```

This is a known issue with Xcode 10. Automatic Fix-it is not working correctly for Swift 4.2 when it comes to correcting notification names.

In Swift 4.2, lots of `Notification.Name` instances became instance variables in other classes. For example, `keyboardWillShowNotification` is now an instance variable of `UIResponder`.

Comment: I didn't know this: ' Automatic Fix-it is not working correctly for Swift 4.2 when it comes to correcting notification names.'  (Thanks a lot)

Comment: No luck for this code ....Implemented this code in UIWindow class "NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.bringWindow(toTop:)), name: UIWindow.didBecomeVisibleNotification, object: nil)"

Comment: Getting `Cannot invoke 'addObserver' with an argument list of type '(RegistrationViewController, selector: Selector, name: NSNotification.Name)'`

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan Sorry about that, Madhu_Nani was right - `object: nil` was missing. I've edited my post

Answer (score 1):

For someone else out there, I was building (what I thought was) a UI-Independent class and did not import UIKit.

Nothing worked until I added at the top of my file, this:

```
import UIKit
```

It appears some notifications (those in UIApplication, UIResponder etc..) may have been refactored into UIKIt.

Answer (score 0):

The selected [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52466256/1084174) is incomplete and produce compilers error,

> Cannot invoke 'addObserver' with an argument list of type
>   '(RegistrationViewController, selector: Selector, name:
>   NSNotification.Name)'

Here is the working format,

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
```