# Type 'NSNotification.Name' has no member 'UIResponder'

Tags: swift5

I'm getting this error with Swift 5

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

[image]

also I'm getting below error

'Name' is not a member type of 'Notification'

```
public let ImagePickerTrayDidHide: Notification.Name = Notification.Name(rawValue: "ch.laurinbrandner.ImagePickerTrayDidHide")
```

how I can fix that?

Comment: This will help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52316676/type-nsnotification-name-has-no-member-keyboarddidshownotification/52325564#52325564

Comment: @RakeshaShastri I can't understand because my code is a little bit different, can you explain for me?

Comment: Your code is wrong. Not different. The right way to do it is mentioned in the link.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri but that's work on swift 3, can you fix this issue and post an answer?

Comment: Where does it say Swift 3 there? It clearly says Swift 4.2. Did you even check the link?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix this issue with the UIResponder as not recognized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55787125/how-to-fix-this-issue-with-the-uiresponder-as-not-recognized) and [Moving UITextField up with keyboard - changes in swift 4.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53082764/moving-uitextfield-up-with-keyboard-changes-in-swift-4-2) and [Error with notification names while converting code to Swift 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52466147/error-with-notification-names-while-converting-code-to-swift-4-2)

Answer (score 4):

As I can guess initially you had the following code:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

When you compiled it in Xcode 10.1 you received the following errors: `'keyboardWillShowNotification' has been renamed to 'NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow', Replace 'keyboardWillShowNotification' with 'NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow'` and `'keyboardWillHideNotification' has been renamed to 'NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide', Replace 'keyboardWillHideNotification' with 'NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide'`.

Then you pressed "Fix" twice and get the incorrect code you already added to your question. You should use the following:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace the `NotificationCenter.Name.UIResponder` with `UIResponder`
For Eg:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
self, 
selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow(_:)), 
name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
self, 
selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide(_:)), 
name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

For More details refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52325564/8331006

Answer (score 0):

Replace `UIResponder.NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow` with `.UIKeyboardWillShow`